# Linear Feedback Shift Register Max Period

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am wondering how to find the max period for

$$s_{n+1} = s_n + s_{n-2}$$

with an initial seed of $(s_0,s_1,s_2) = (a,b,c)$ in $Z_2$ which is not equal to $(0,0,0)$.
Can I find the max period of this sequence without trial and error?

Comment: Isn't it possible to calculate it using the coefficient vector?

Comment: S is the coefficient vector

Comment: s0=a,s1=b,s2=c,s3=a+c,s4=a+b+c,s5=a+b+2c,...

Comment: From what I understand the coefficient vector is (1,0,1) as sn+1 = 1*sn + 0*sn-1 + 1*sn-2. I've been told this can be expressed as a feedback polynomial of the form: f(x) = x^3 + x^2 + 1. If this is a primitive polynomial, then the max period can be found....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. The feedback polynomial is, indeed, $f(x)=x^3+x^2+1$. Because
$$
(x^3+x^2+1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+1)=x^7+1,
$$
we see that the maximum period has length $7$.

You are also correct in that $f(x)$ is primitive. Because $2^3-1=7$ happens to be a prime number, any irreducible cubic as a feedback  polynomial will yield the same maximum period. In general the maximum period of a sequence gotten with an irreducible polynomial of degree $m$ is a factor of $2^m-1$, and equal to the maximum iff the polynomial is primitive.

Furthermore, this LFSR will only generate the all zeros sequence and all the seven cyclic shifts of a single $m$-sequence. If the seed is $(s_0,s_1,s_2)=100$ the full period is
$$
1001110\ 1001110\ \ldots
$$
and we easily verify that all the 3-bit subsequences other than $000$ occur exactly once per period (de Bruijn -property).

Comment: Ok so how did you pick $$s_0,s_1,s_2 $$ as 1,0,0 respectively?

Comment: I understand what you said about how $$f(x)$$ is primitive but I don't know how you applied this to generating these seed values that you gave.

Comment: You can pick $s_0,s_1,s_2$ any which way you want unless they are all zeros, and you just get a cyclic shift of the same sequence.

Comment: but will the period always be 7?

Comment: Because I have seen questions that say find the max period and then also say find seeds such that the period equals 4 are these periods never possible provided that the max was 7 and f(x) was primitive?